# OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: sql-server, azure, psycopg2

I am trying to connect a SQL Server database that I created on Azure to my VS Code through psycopg2.

Whenever I try to connect my connection string, I get this error message:

> Operational Error: connection to server at ... port **** failed server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.

Here are a few steps I have taken to fix it that haven't worked:

1. Check my network connection
2. Make sure server is online
3. Check the info being passed in on the connection string

Is there anything else I can do? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the driver you're using? `psycopg2` is for connecting to PostgreSQL databases. PostgreSQL is a completely different relational database management system than Microsoft SQL Server (and Azure SQL) and uses different communication protocols and connection drivers. Seems like you might want to use `pyodbc` and `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server` (or later) in your own Python code, or if you're after VS Code extensions maybe try the `mssql` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to connect PostgreSQL database in my environment using below code:

```
import psycopg2
host = "<servername>"
dbname = "<dbName>"
user = "<userName>"
password = "<password>"
sslmode = "require"
conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string) 
print("Connection established")
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

I got below error:

[image]

I allowed public IP address and added client IP address to the server

[image]

Tried once to connect, it connected successfully.

[image]